# Applying a function to all elements of a list to create new columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have the following function:

```
get_ym = function(x) {
   paste0(str_replace(str_sub(deparse(substitute(x)), start= -11, end = -5), "[.]","-"), "-01")
}
```

When applied to a single object, it works fine, like here:

```
get_ym(device.2019.01.csv)
[1] "2019-01-01"
```

I want to apply this function to a list of objects which are essentially the same, but with different dates, like device.2019.02.csv, device.2020.03.csv, and so.

When I use lapply, the output is not what I want.

```
lapply(device_files, get_ym)
[[1]]
[1] "X[-01"

[[2]]
[1] "X[-01"
```

and so on.

Furthermore, I'd like to create new columns in all objects from the list using the get_ym function. So I wrote

```
apply_ym = function(x) {
  x$month = get_ym(x)
}
apply_ym(device.2020.03.csv)
```

But this doesn't work on a single object, not to mention when applied to a list.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

device_files are a list of objects created like so:

```
device_files = list.files(pattern = "^device.2")
device_files = strsplit(device_files, split = " ")
```

Comment: how does your "device_files" list look / how do you create it

Comment: device_files = list.files(pattern = "^device.2") 
device_files = strsplit(device_files, split = " ")
It's a list of files based on a pattern, there are 18 files.

Comment: @Ronak Shah is right, it seems getting rid of the substitute() will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code which you have written is for unquoted variables.

```
get_ym(device.2019.01.csv)
[1] "2019-01-01"
```

It does not work when you pass quoted variables.

```
get_ym('device.2019.01.csv')
[1] "019-01.-01"
```

When you use `list.files` you get output as character variable. So change your function to :

```
library(stringr)
get_ym = function(x) {
  paste0(str_replace(str_sub(x, start= -11, end = -5), "[.]","-"), "-01")
}
```

and use it as. :

```
x <- c('device.2019.02.csv', 'device.2020.03.csv')
sapply(x, get_ym, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "2019-02-01" "2020-03-01"
```

---

To add new column, you can use `mget` with `Map` :

```
device_files = list.files(pattern = "^device.2")
all_data <- Map(cbind, mget(device_files), 
                       filename = sapply(device_files, get_ym))
```

Comment: This works great for the first part of my question, thanks. Now I want to use the output to add columns called "month" to all objects in the list where the value is the previous output, how do I do that?